# How to read/consume SegY File in R

Tags: r

There is a package called `Rquake`, which is used for the estimation and analysis of seismic data.

But there is no such relevant examples out there.
I basically wanted to kow how to use this package, I have referred a PDF https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rquake/Rquake.pdf  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rquake/versions/2.4-0/topics/Rquake-package
...but didn't found anything relevant.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?  I'm in the same situation!

Comment: Nope... Didnt found anything relevant.. @James Adam Campbell